# Upgrade menu missing in VS Professional?

Tags: visual-studio

In my enterprise edition I have (when right clicking on a project in Solution Explorer)

[image]

But it seems to be missing from my Professional edition installation. I could be mistaken, I may have taken some action previously that causes this menu to appear.

Answer (score 0):

Install .NET Upgrade assistant again (you may have done this before and targeted an older installation of Visual Studio such as an Enterprise edition) and this time target the newer installation of Visual Studio Pro.